# If a Exception is thrown is their way the program can continue execution and take the user's input?

Tags: java, try-catch

I just recently learned about the try/catch block and how once the expection is thrown the program will exit. In the photo below the code the Expection is caught once the user enters "a" instead of a random number.

Is there any way the user could reenter the value without the Expection being thrown again?

```java
import java.util.Scanner
public class user_Num {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int random_Num = 0;
        try {
            System.out.println("Enter a random number:");
            random_Num = input.nextInt();
            if (random_Num > 0) {
                System.out.println("The user entered a number that is positive.");
            } else if (random_Num<0) {
                System.out.println("The user entered a number that is negative");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }
        System.out.println("Enter a random number:");
        random_Num = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("User Input Taken.");
    }
}
```

Program Result:

[image]

Comment: I'm not going to give you a code example, but rather a hint for you to do it yourself: Create a `while` loop, which checks for a `boolean` variable. If you read correct input, you set the variable to `true`, so there has to be no more input read and the loop will be exited. If you encounter the error, you don't change it so you re-enter the loop and read the input again.

Comment: The fact that an exception has occurred does not mean the program has to exit. You can handle it in any way you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this is pretty easy you just have to revert back to whole code in the catch block. You could also have a thread.

```
import java.util.Scanner
        public class user_Num{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         int random_Num = 0;
               
         Thread t1=new Thread(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run()
                  {
                    System.out.println("Enter a random number:");
                      random_Num = input.nextInt();
                      if(random_Num > 0){
                          System.out.println("The user entered a number that is 
                          positive.");
                      } else if (random_Num < 0){
                          System.out.println("The user entered a number that is 
                          negative");
                      }

                  }
              });
                  try {

                       t1.start();
                       t1.close();
                                        } catch (Exception e){
                      System.out.println("Error: " +e);
                      System.out.println("Your input is not a number.");
                      t1.start();
                    
                }
            }
          }
        }
```